# Application crashes on KitKat

Tags: java, android

I have tested the application on newer devices, but on older phones I get a crash I don't understand:

```
  E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
    Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
    Shutting down VM
    threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d35b20)
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: md.darwin.catalog, PID: 1271
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: md.darwin.catalog.utils.AnalyticsTrackers$1
    at md.darwin.catalog.utils.AnalyticsTrackers.get(AnalyticsTrackers.java:64)
    at md.darwin.catalog.utils.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:27)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I suppose it may be related to Google Analytics, but why would `getGoogleAppId` fail? any clue on how to solve this issue?

---

Update
`MyApplication`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
        .getSimpleName();

private static MyApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;

    AnalyticsTrackers.initialize(this);
    AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
}

public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public synchronized Tracker getGoogleAnalyticsTracker() {
    AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTrackers = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();
    return analyticsTrackers.get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP);
}
 // and the other methods related to GA
```

Here is AnalyticsTrackers

```
// AnalyticsTrackers 
public final class AnalyticsTrackers {

public enum Target {
    APP
}

private static AnalyticsTrackers sInstance;

public static synchronized void initialize(Context context) {
    if (sInstance != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Extra call to initialize analytics trackers");
    }

    sInstance = new AnalyticsTrackers(context);
}

public static synchronized AnalyticsTrackers getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Call initialize() before getInstance()");
    }

    return sInstance;
}

private final Map<Target, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<Target, Tracker>();
private final Context mContext;

/**
 * Don't instantiate directly - use {@link #getInstance()} instead.
 */
private AnalyticsTrackers(Context context) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}

public synchronized Tracker get(Target target) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(target)) {
        Tracker tracker;

            switch (target) {
                case APP:
                    tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mContext).newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled analytics target " + target);
            }
            mTrackers.put(target, tracker);


    }

    return mTrackers.get(target);
}
```

}

Comment: What is `md.darwin.catalog.utils.AnalyticsTrackers$1` ($1 means it's an anonymous inner class in there, some runnable or listener most likely)? It complaints that it can't find that. And is there no `caused by` part afterwards? Class loading issues are often issues with the build system, so how do you build the app?

Comment: Can you post your google Analytic code

Comment: also what version of play are you using

Comment: @zapl: I updated the question, please have a look.
google play services version: 8115000

Comment: Did you have some anonymous inner class in there before? I don't see one. If so, maybe you simply need to run "gradle clean" or equivalent to get rid of some outdated class files that made it into the app.

Comment: nope, any. I just don't get it, why does this happen on 4.4.4 but on 5+ does not?

Comment: @FilipLuch Do you have compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0' in your build.gradle ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with `multidex`; Lollipop handles it in a different way than KitKat does. If I got it right, In KitKat, the system cannot find declared classes in one dex file, which are located in another one, so it crashes. It is important that when adding `multiDexEnabled true` in `build.gradle`, you also have to set multidex inside Application class:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

or if you don't have an Application class, create it, and then set multidex.

http://frogermcs.github.io/MultiDex-solution-for-64k-limit-in-Dalvik/